# How to best write multiple functons that use the same mutexes

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some code that looks like this:

```
g_mutex

void foo()
{
g_mutex.lock();
...
g_mutex.unlock()
}

void foobar()
{
g_mutex.lock();
...
g_mutex.unlock()

foo();

g_mutex.lock();
...
g_mutex.unlock()
}
```

Is there a pattern I can use such that in foobar() I can just lock the mutex once?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You seem to be describing [reentrant mutexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

## 1. Use `std::recursive_mutex`

This way there's no problem if the same thread locks the mutex more than once, you don't have to unlock it before calling the function.

Use `lock_guard` or `unique_lock` though, don't litter your code with lock/unlock pairs.

## 2. Make foo() take a guard as argument

Rewrite `foo()` like this:

```
void foo(lock_guard<mutex>&)
{
    // do foo stuff
}
```

This way it's impossible to call `foo()` without a mutex being locked. The `lock_guard` object is a token saying `foo()` can only be called with synchronization. Of course, it's still possible to mess it up by locking an unrelated mutex (which is rare if you are implementing the methods of a class, there's only one mutex visible to be locked).

You can see more details of this approach on [this Andrei's pre-C++-11 article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25298).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard):

```
void foobar()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_mutex);
    // ...
} // releases g_mutex automatically
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you rely on the mutex being reentrant - that is, it can be locked many times by the same thread:

```
void foo() {
   g_mutex.lock();
   // do foo stuff
   g_mutex.unlock();
}

void foobar() {
   g_mutex.lock();
   foo();
   g_mutex.unlock();
}
```

If you don't want that for some reason, there is a messier approach but it's not recommended.  This would typically be done only in a class, where you can restrict access to private functions.

```
void foo_private()
{
    // do foo stuff with the assumption that the lock is acquired.
}

void foo() {
   g_mutex.lock();
   foo_private();
   g_mutex.unlock();
}

void foobar() {
   g_mutex.lock();
   foo_private();
   g_mutex.unlock();
}
```

Also, as stated in the other answer to your question, you should use `std::lock_guard` to acquire the lock, as it will correctly unlock your object in the event of an exception (or if you forget to).